# i have to click twice to let the datepicker show

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

i created a jquery code showing the datepicker, it works perfectly but i need to click the textbox twice to let the datepicker go out. i trid using `$(document).ready(function ()` but i doesnt work. so i made this code

```
$("[id*=txtDatePO]").live("click",function () {
        $(this).datepicker({
            //buttonImage: '../Images/Icons/calendar_1_icon&16.png',
            //buttonImageOnly: true,
            //showOn: 'both',
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            inline: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']

        });
    });

    $("[id*=txtDelDate]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            inline: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
        });
    });
```

how can i change it to when the user clicks the textbox once, the calendar will display with one click. thanks!

Comment: Well, you move it to `document.ready`. What exactly did not work with that approach?

Comment: jQuery live is deprecated, use on instead: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Are the date picker elements added dynamically?

Comment: @Esko 'on' is not working.

Comment: @AdamAzad what do you mean dynamically?

Comment: @andrei Hi, the datepicker does not show when i put it in `document.ready`

Comment: @JediAblaza are you saying that jQuery does not work and is the culprit here? It's your code that is not working, but it's hard to help you with this little information.

Comment: @JediAblaza, I mean using `append()` or `appendTo()` or `.html()` to add the elements to the page. The question lacking information to address the issue. Try to clarify by adding the HTML (if any) and a minimal verified example

Comment: Please show us how the code looks like when you use `document.ready`. We should be able to correct that, and that will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I've never used date-picker though If I'm understanding correctly the click event seems to be built in:

Here's an example i forked and modified to test on both existing and a dynamic (created) element:
http://jsfiddle.net/julienetienne/shzwaL7v/1/

```
var dynamicElement = document.createElement('input');
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('result')[0];

dynamicElement.id = 'input3';
dynamicElement.type ='text';
document.body.insertBefore(dynamicElement,$('#input2').get(0));

$('#input1').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});

$('#input2').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});

$(dynamicElement).datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});



<input id="input1" type="text" />
<input id="input2" type="text" />
```

There shouldn't be a reason to use document.ready() or .live(). As long as the code is being executed after page load it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It should be on `document ready`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#txtDatePO').datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            orientation: "bottom left",
            autoclose: true
     });
});
```

btw, this sample bootstrap datepicker

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind datepicker("show") with your click event this works for me

```
$("[id*=txtDatePO]").live("click",function () {
    $(this).datepicker({
        //buttonImage: '../Images/Icons/calendar_1_icon&16.png',
        //buttonImageOnly: true,
        //showOn: 'both',
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        inline: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']

    }).datepicker("show");
});
```